# Very weird behavior of video dimensions

Tags: video, video-editor

I have a video (for some testing), when I check dimensions in properties, it says 640x1136 pixels.

[image]

To cross check dimensions, I played it in VLC media player and took a snapshot from there, which also had same dimensions.

But here comes the issue which I couldn't solve in last 2 hours.

I created a sequence in Premier with 1280x1136 dimensions. So it should fit 2 videos of same size side by side right? But isn't working as intended.

It is cropping a bit the 2nd video (preview from Premiere):

[image]

[image]

I exported the video and imported in Photoshop to cross check, and I saw same preview. But Photoshop document properties also says:

[image]

So it made me wonder how it can be possible.

What seems here is video is more wider actually than 640 pixels. I manually *measured left side of video preview, which showed approximately 703 pixels in Photoshop and hence the canvas is a bit narrow for fitting both videos.

But I just don't understand why is it happening? Could it be some problem with video itself? Could it be true that real dimensions of this video are 703x1136 and it is showing 640 by some mistake?